# How to lock app in recent applications tab in oppo devices programmatically?

Tags: android, service

I want to lock my application in recent applications in oppo phones as shown in the image programmatically so that I can run my services in the background after the application has been killed. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution. I am also stuck in almost same situation??

Comment: When you in recent screen just hold and pull down the app then release, and lock icon will appear.. i allready try to my oppo A39.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure app is **on**.
2. Go to **recent apps** (which is the square button you always press to clear background apps).
3. Instead of swiping up to clear the app, you **swipe down** to lock/unlock the app.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to this programmatically :)